# Negative R squared but with close predictions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm getting a pretty bad $R^2$, negative in fact, but the graph, where predicted values are plotted over test values, looks very solid. How is this possible? I'm quite new to DS and have never faced issue like this so any feedback would be very helpful.

**$R^2$ metric result:**

[image]

**Graph of lasso regression:**
[image]

**Graph of ridge regression** (in comparison to lasso, because its $R^2$ actually makes sense):

[image]

**PS: code snippet with graph creation:**

```py
model = Lasso()

yHat = model.predict(X_test)
mae_test = mae(y_test, yHat)
r2_test = r2_score(y_test, yHat)
_yHat = yHat

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,7))
ax.plot(sorted(y_test), color='blue', label='test', linestyle='dashed')
ax.plot(sorted(_yHat), color="r", label='prediction', linewidth=.5)
fig.suptitle(name)
fig.legend(loc='best')
fig.tight_layout()
```

**PPS: predicted values over true values:**
[image]

Comment: What do those graphs show? How did you create it? Have you looked at the graphs showing the raw data points vs predictions? What is your data?

Comment: @Tim , As I've mentioned, these are graphs, where predicted values are plotted over test values. I have updated the question with a code snippet where graph is being created.

Comment: take a look here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/246353/56940

Comment: An answer requires someone looking at the documentation or the code of `r2_score()` to see its precise definition. Assuming the code is competent, the definition is evidently not just the square of the correlation between two variables.

Comment: Plot predictions vs. true values (i.e. predictions as the y-axis, true values as the x-axis)

Comment: A conjecture: Is it possible that the reported "r2" this not R-squared, but adjusted R-squared?

Comment: It is very clear that there is a consistent negative bias in LASSO, that will lead to negative R-squared

Comment: @cdalitz No, the function follows the regular formula for r squared: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score

Comment: @Firebug Yes, but how is it possible that the predicted values overlay the true values so close?

Comment: I don't see any conflict with that. Given true values $X$ and predictions $Y = X+c$, for $c$ constant, it's easy to see that the correlation $\text{Cor}(X,Y)=1$, and that  $\lim_{c \to \infty} R^2 = -\infty$

Comment: @Firebug but wouldn't that mean that the residuals are very high, which means that the $y$ and $\hat{y}$ should be very different?

Comment: @Firebug Can you please explain how "it's easy to see" that a value that is known to be between 0 and 1 for linear regression (for a simple proof, see the Wikipedia entry on "Explained sum of squares") becomes minus infinity?

Comment: Your plots are not showing data, they show lines. Unlikely your data is a function rather than points.

Comment: @cdalitz $$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum_i (y_i - \bar y)^2} $$

Comment: @cdalitz Also, don't confuse in-sample linear regression results to out-of-sample not-linear regression results

Comment: @JoshJohnson Again, plot the predictions versus the true values, you are going to see what I mean

Comment: @Firebug So according to formula the difference between predicted and true values is larger than the difference between mean and true values, however on the graph that I've added it looks like there little to no difference. I'm sorry, I don't quite follow.

Comment: You are plotting the sorted values, it will always look like there is a relation

Comment: Also, you are always plotting the indices in the x-axis, that plot is generally not useful. Plotting the predictions in the y-axis and the true values in x-axis is much more useful to understand the performance of a model

Comment: Say there are three observations: the true values are $y = [1, 2, 3]$ and the predicted values are $\hat{y} = [3, 2, 1]$. The order of the observations matters because you need to match each true value with its corresponding prediction; by sorting the true values and the predictions *separately* the ordering is lost. So you are plotting: `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]` while actually you want to plot the pairs `[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As can be seen in the code, you are plotting sorted values of both predictions and true values.
That will lead to a visually apparent pattern where there is none, leading to rank-correlation equal to 1.

What you should plot instead is the raw predictions in the y-axis and the true values in the x-axis. That way, it should be clearer why R-squared is negative. Remember, this is out-of-sample. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183279/60613) to understand why this is possible.

Comment: Also see [this question + answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185507/what-happens-if-the-explanatory-and-response-variables-are-sorted-independently) about why you should never compare two sets of independently sorted data. It's meaningless. If you have a good reason to sort one set of values, then you need to use the same sorting indices for the other so that paired observations remain correctly paired.